# C2572 - When trying to include a function with a default parameter in another file, and then include this file in main

Tags: c++, preprocessor, default-parameters

I am trying to build a small program in C++, to learn the preprocessor directives and how they actually work.

The program is made up of 5 files: `main.cpp`, `file1.h`, `file1.cpp`, `file2.h` and `file2.cpp`

In `file1.h`, I declared 1 function that has the default parameter, and a new type byte:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

byte f1(byte a, byte b = 5);
```

In `file1.cpp`, I defined it:

```
#include "file1.h"

byte f1(byte a, byte b) {

    return a + b;
}
```

In `file2.h`, I declared a second function that uses `f1()`, and always passes 10 to it as a second argument:

```
#include "file1.h"

byte f2(byte a);
```

And the same, in `file2.cpp`, I defined it:

```
#include "file2.h"

byte f2(byte a) {

    return f1(a, 10);
}
```

And finally, here is the main file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "file1.h"

int main() {

    cout << f1(3) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

For now, all is Ok, and the output is simply `8`.

But suppose I need to use the `f2()` function in my main file, and for that I included
the `file2.h`, so the main file is now:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

int main() {

    cout << (int) f1(3) << endl;

    cout << (int) f2(2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is giving this error: `Error   C2572   'f1': redefinition of default argument: parameter 1`

Since `file1.h` is included in `file2.h`, now `f1()` is redeclared in `file2.h` with the `b` paramter also set to `5`.

What can I do to prevent the redefinition, if we assume that I can not move the `f2()` declaration and definition to `file1.h` and `file1.cpp` respectively?

Note: I know that I could use `#pragma once` directive, but I am trying to solve this problem without it, since I am trying to learn the C++ directives professionally.

Comment: The `#include "file1.h"` statement does not belong in `file2.h`, since nothing in `file2.h` is dependent on what is declared in `file1.h` . That statement should be moved inside of `file2.cpp` instead, where the content of `file1.h` (ie, the declaration of `f1()`) is actually being used.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Yes, my problem was solved with your proposal, but I want to apologize for forgetting to introduce a dependency from `file2.h` to `file1.h`, because that how it is in my real case. I have edited the question, and replaced `int` by `byte` as a return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code shown, `byte` and `f1()` are being declared multiple times in `main.cpp` when `file1.h` and `file2.h` are both `#include`'d.

Per the C++ standard, [§8.3.6 [dcl.fct.default]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#note-2):

> [Note 2: A default argument cannot be redefined by a later declaration (not even to the same value) ([[basic.def.odr]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr)). — end note]

Which is exactly what is happening here.

> Note: I know that I could use `#pragma once` directive, but I am trying to solve this problem without it, since I am trying to learn the C++ directives professionally.

Making your `.h` files have proper header guards (see [#pragma once vs include guards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/)) is the correct and professional way to avoid redeclarations, eg:

`file1.h`:

```
#ifndef File1H
#define File1H

typedef unsigned char byte;

byte f1(byte a, byte b = 5);

#endif
```

`file2.h`:

```
#ifndef File2H
#define File2H

#include "file1.h"

byte f2(byte a);

#endif
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rsluf83N2)

Comment: I agree to this, but there just one thing, in `f1()`, if you make `b` a non-default parameter, it will compile normally without any `#pragma once` or preprocessor directive. So why does in the case of a default parameter it need all that, whereas it needs nothing in the case of normal parameters?

Comment: @XY because the C++ standard doesn't allow default parameters in multiple declarations. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6708956/65863) to [Multiple declarations of C++ functions with default parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708726/)

Comment: That is okay! And just as a remark, this can solve the problem: `int f(int a, int b #ifndef FILE1_H #define FILE1H = 5 #endif);`
The preprocessor directives can simply be used around the default parameter value.

Comment: @XY that is a *terrible* solution. For one thing, it has a typo in it. For another, it will completely disable `file1.h` if proper header guards are implemented later.